# Large text file search in larger text file

Tags: text, full-text-search, emeditor

Been using EmEditor for most of my document handling and its been great over the years. However recently came into another request and now need to use a semi-large searchfile.txt (1GB) to search for alphanumerical values inside an even larger textfile.txt (+500GB). Its basically impossible even though EmEditor claims to be able to "Easily handle files up to 16TB". Clearly there's a limit.

I don't want to split the files and run several times, as that will just be way to boring and requires a lot of job my end. If splitting files is required it would be great if that could be done automatically (script?). Have tried indexing in Windows and that is incredibly fast but its limited to 1 (one) of the 10+ million lines inside the 1GB searchfile.txt, so that won't work.

Its also a possibility I will get this request every few weeks from now on and they are talking about text-files well above 1TB. Maybe as large as 10TB (need to buy a new drive for sure). So any suggestion on how to proceed?

Have tried EmEditor and indexing in Windows search. Also searched online to a solution but so far drew blank.

Comment: I'm not sure which tool in EmEditor you tried. Did you try the [Batch Find](https://www.emeditor.com/text-editor-features/coding/batch-replace/) feature?

Comment: Yes, been using Batch Finder. But it only accepts around 33MB. Split the original files into 30 files. So it takes forever.

Comment: Been writing a program in Rust. Works good on small text-files, but 500GB it crashes on.

Comment: This is probably a bug in EmEditor. Please send us a bug report with the [contact form](https://www.emeditor.com/support/#contact) so we can hopefully resolve the issue. In the message, please let us know what happened when you tried to Import the searchfile.txt in Batch Find. Since this could be memory-related, also include how much memory is available in your system.

Comment: I received your crash report. EmEditor crashed becuase the system is low in memory. Please use **Linked File** when you create the batch list in the **Batch Find** dialog box. To create a linked file, you can drag and drop the keyword list to the empty batch list, or click the down arrow by the **Add to Batch** button and select **Add a Linked File**.
I would also use **Advanced Filter** instead. Please see https://youtu.be/fBXL0LIuZiU?si=zAMdh-VCDJiD5f6D and https://youtu.be/faRECnE61Hs?si=ZfC-7TYmvsGWZqHs

Comment: Thanks, can tell the the suggestion to use the Advanced Filter function worked like a charm. 1GB text file with 30 million lines is searching in a 46GB text file with 1+ billion lines.
Also followed the advise and changed the Windows system settings for the paging file.
Decided to upgrade to a full version for one year. Don't think I really need the expert mode but think I should support as the editor clearly is great.
Now I only need to buy a new computer with a large ram...